# How to use linq to entities queries or Lists in linq to sql queries

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have a generic EF repository and need to get items from database using nested where statements.

```
var categoryGroups = repository.Categories.Where(a => a.Vehicles.Where(v => 
                   bodyTypesFilter.Any(b => b == v.BodyType)).Count() > 0);
```

I include only the important part of lambda expression.
Here bodyTypesFilter is a List and I'm getting following exception.

Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

I understand that it's due to I'm trying to generate linq to sql query which includes List and it isn't allowed. But I don't know how to avoid it or overcome.

Please help to find out a solution.

Comment: are any of the elements of `bodyTypesFilter` null?

Comment: explain what do you want to get as result.

Comment: Yes @Ben it's null when throwing exception

Comment: I want to get those items for which vehicles bodyType is contained in bodyTypesFilter List

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284497/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-system-collections

Answer (score 1):

It's about the part

```
bodyTypesFilter.Any(b => b == v.BodyType)
```

You can't compare objects in EF queries, because the part `bodyTypesFilter` can't be translated into SQL. Do this in stead:

```
bodyTypesFilterIds.Contains(v.BodyType.Id)
```

(or probably `v.BodyTypeId`)

where `bodyTypesFilterIds` is a list of Id values in stead of objects.

(Not `Any`, because that creates a monster query that easily develops into a too deep nesting level).