# Referencing null from somewhere I didn't know where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I thought I covered every null possibility, but this line:

```
double indicatorValue = 
    step2.Count() > 0 ? step2.Sum(iv => ((double?)iv.Value) ?? 0d) : 0d;
```

gives me this error:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

Please, I had read some posts and none points me to the correct way.

EDIT: relevant code?

```
var step1 = db.IndicatorValues
    .Where(iv =>
        iv.Year == _ano &&
        iv.IdIndicator == item.IdIndicator &&
        idSites.Contains(iv.IdSite)
    );

var step2 = step1.Where(iv => 
    (isYTD == true ? iv.Month <= _mes : iv.Month == _mes)
);
```

Comment: What exactly is `step2`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney. I had posted the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284497/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-system-collections

Comment: What is the type of `iv.Value`?

Comment: @IvanStoev. It is decimal.

Comment: do you mean the type is decimal? (nullable decimal)

Comment: Hmm, strange, I don't see any arrays in your code. For the sake of test, could you try `var indicatorValue = step2.Sum(iv => iv.Value);`

Comment: @IvanStoev. It shows: `The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`

Comment: Then use `((decimal?)iv.Value) ?? 0m`. I'm trying to eliminate the comversion. Anyway, I've tried something similar (EF6, SqlServer db)) and it works. What you can do is to start eliminating the parts. `var res1 = step1.ToList();`. If no exception, `var res2 = step2.ToList();` etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev. `(decimal?)` instead `(double?)` gives the same error. And checking _res1_ and _res2_ shows count `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "null" case I can see is the following:

```
class Program
{

    class Test
    {
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var step2 = new Test[] { null };

        double indicatorValue = step2.Count() > 0 ? step2.Sum(iv => ((double?)iv.Value) ?? 0d) : 0d;

        Console.WriteLine(indicatorValue);
    }
}
```

this gives me NullReferrence Exception

for further diagnostic of your problem I would recommend on a stage of debug instead of `step2` variable in your expression to use `step2Test =  step2.ToArray()`

On a stage of getting the array instance you might have the same error as you wrote in your description, then there is nothing to do with the logic of `indicatorValue` calculation

The error about null in int array can be here: `idSites.Contains(iv.IdSite)`
possible issue `iv.IdSite` is null in a particular case

Please try the following instead

```
idSites.Contains(iv.IdSite)
```

put

```
iv.IdSites == null ? false : ( idSites == null ? false : idSites.Contains(iv.IdSite))
```

Comment: You are right, my `int[] idSites` got null somewhere. I've added one if for that and all works fine now.. I'm feeling embarrassed for not seeing it before... many thanks dude!!

Comment: then you should replace this instruction. will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

`step1` and `step2` are *IQueryable* and not *IEnumerable* so Linq wants to convert `((double?)iv.Value) ?? 0d` into a SQL statement.

Depending on the rest of the code (`step1` and `step2` are used for something else) you can fix this by:

a. converting `step2` to an in-memory collection (e.g. using `.ToList()`)

b. filter in step2 the IndicatorValues that are `null`.

c. `double indicatorValue = step2.Count() > 0 ? step2.Where(iv => iv.HasValue).Sum(iv => iv.Value) : 0d;`

Not sure what is `iv.Value` type and why do you need it converted to double? but one of these solutions will probably work.

Comment: Strange, I tried your `a`-fix, and the error went to its line. =/

Comment: Thank you too.. Just a note, visual studio refused `iv.HasValue` as not recognized.